# Cannot load Instagram profiles in AngularJS ng-views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, instagram, ng-bind-html

I'm trying to embed an Instagram profile:

```js
$scope.instagram = "<blockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-version=\"4\" style=\" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);\"><div style=\"padding:8px;\"> <div style=\" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;\"> <div style=\" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAAGFBMVEUiIiI9PT0eHh4gIB4hIBkcHBwcHBwcHBydr+JQAAAACHRSTlMABA4YHyQsM5jtaMwAAADfSURBVDjL7ZVBEgMhCAQBAf//42xcNbpAqakcM0ftUmFAAIBE81IqBJdS3lS6zs3bIpB9WED3YYXFPmHRfT8sgyrCP1x8uEUxLMzNWElFOYCV6mHWWwMzdPEKHlhLw7NWJqkHc4uIZphavDzA2JPzUDsBZziNae2S6owH8xPmX8G7zzgKEOPUoYHvGz1TBCxMkd3kwNVbU0gKHkx+iZILf77IofhrY1nYFnB/lQPb79drWOyJVa/DAvg9B/rLB4cC+Nqgdz/TvBbBnr6GBReqn/nRmDgaQEej7WhonozjF+Y2I/fZou/qAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;\"></div></div><p style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;\"><a href=\"https://instagram.com/p/1yaMWyoVZM/\" style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none;\" target=\"_top\">Une photo publiée par National Geographic (@natgeo)</a> le <time style=\" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;\" datetime=\"2015-04-22T18:41:49+00:00\">22 Avril 2015 à 11h41 PDT</time></p></div></blockquote>\n<script async defer src=\"//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js\"></script>";
```

But when displaying it within an `ng-view` (where `trust` simply calls `$sce.trustAsHtml`):

```html
<div ng-bind-html="instagram | trust"></div>
```

The profile does not load. Any idea why? I think it has something to do with the `script` tag at the end of the Instagram embed HTML, but I haven't found a solution yet:

```html
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4l3UIioCeRi5S6Xtzbq?p=preview) you can play with, see how it should look like on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdnr0454/).

Comment: Hmmm, is it possible that Angular is bootstrapping before the instagram script has fully loaded? Is there a callback that the instagram script calls when it's ready? If there's one, maybe manual bootstrap Angular inside that? Or maybe try removing `async` and `defer` from the instagram `script` tag...

Comment: @MKSafi I already tried removing the `async` and `defer` attributes, but it did not work. I don't really know what the included script does, it's a bit hard to read: http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js. Do you get something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40855386/5537365 This is everything you need. This worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it has something to do with the script tag at the end of the Instagram embed HTML

Yes, it does; and it seems the way the HTML is inserted with ng-bind prevents it from working.

---

You could copy/paste the script to the index page:

```
 <script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

and display your image by adding a $timeout in your controller:

```
$timeout(function(){
  $window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
});
```

---

See [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cOHF1Q?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I used only

```
$timeout(function(){
  $window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
});
```

without

```
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

and works!

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js create a directive for adding script element:

```
.directive('externalscript', function() {
    var injectScript = function(element) {
        var instagramScript = angular.element(document.createElement('script'));
        instagramScript.attr('async defer');
        instagramScript.attr('charset', 'utf-8');
        instagramScript.attr('src','http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js');
        instagramScript.attr('onload', 'window.instgrm.Embeds.process()');
        element.append(instagramScript);
        var twitterScript = angular.element(document.createElement('script'));
        twitterScript.attr('async defer');
        twitterScript.attr('charset', 'utf-8');
        twitterScript.attr('src', 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
        element.append(twitterScript);
    };

    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {
          injectScript(element);
      }
    };
})
```

and then in your html view call:

```
<div externalscript></div>
```