# Instagram embeds.js library not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed, instagram, oembed

I have a javascript function which loads the HTML embed code for an Instagram post. The post appears but the photo is replaced by a grey background and the Instagram logo. The post does contain other information such as hashtags, time posted and username. I believe that the problem is that Instagram embeds.js JavaScript library is not loading properly. I am aware I can do this manually but am having difficulty with how to do this in terms of syntax and placement in my code. Below is my code.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var auto_refresh = setInterval(
         (function () {
            $("#latestData").load("displayPost.php");//displayPost.php "echo" html embed code
         }), 10000);
     </script>

<div id="latestData"></div>
    <script src="https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
    <script>if ( typeof window.instgrm !== 'undefined' ) {
        window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
    }</script>
```

I have used these to try to solve this problem.

[Instagram embeds not working when adding embeds dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408917/instagram-embeds-not-working-when-adding-embeds-dynamically)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170857/problems-using-wps-oembed-function-instagram-ajax

https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/?hl=en

Comment: Okay I have found if I run the embeds function on a timer the instagram post will load correctly but I feel like there must be a more efficient way to do this. Below is the code I added. <script type="text/javascript">
'var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
      window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
   
}), 100);
</script>

Answer (score 9):

This is happening because you're not properly structuring your order of execution. You should load your embed code first, then *in a callback* call `instgrm.Embeds.process()`. Make sure that you do not include embeds.js with each embed by appending `OMITSCRIPT=true` to your embed URL. Instead, include the embeds.js *once* in a script tag on your page.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I loaded the embed code in the header of my html and appended OMITSCRIPT=true to the URL. I'm still not sure about how to call instgrm.Emeds.process(). This is how I currently am calling it. `<script type="text/javascript">
   var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
     $("#latestData").load("displayPost.php");
    window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
}), 5000);
</script>`

Comment: This is the url to include instagram's embeds.js, kinda hard to find. `<script src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>`