# Instagram embedding not working safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari, instagram

I am creating an Instagram feed dynamically from AJAX. It wasn't 'rendering', so after researching I found the following answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27409565/3316722

which says, call this...

```
window.instgrm.Embeds.process()
```

I was excited when it worked on Chrome, but it did not work in Safari, either on desktop or mobile. I opened console log in Safari and ran that code, but it did nothing, whereas it works from Chrome console.

I thought it may be a dynamic issue, so I put the feed on a static page and the instagram posts are still not 'rendering' properly.

Lost entire day, can't find any more details. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome mobile either. Just Chrome desktop

Comment: Maybe it's some sort of conflict with Wordpress?

Comment: Holy cow - I just figured out the cause, but now I really don't know what to do. It appears I must be logged in to Instagram on each browser in order for the rendering to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you must be logged in to Instagram on each browser in order for the rendering to work properly.

Comment: The answer to this was that Instagram may have had a bug in their script because I changed nothing and it started working again. Yay!!!